# Find if a permutation (using + and -) on a string of integers matches a number

Tags: java, algorithm

Basically what I am doing it taking a string of integers (e.g. "1234"), and I am able to insert a + or - anywhere in this string, as much or little as I want. For example, I can do "1 + 2 + 3 + 4", "12 + 34", "123 - 4", etc. It is required to use all integers of the string, I cannot exclude any.

What I am trying to do is take another array of integers, and find if it was possible to get that number using the permutations mentioned in the first paragraph. I am somewhat lost on where to start looking for this. I could possibly create a recursive loop function to create every possible combination of the string and see if each result matches but this seems like it will be terribly slow. Another thought was to index them into an array - that way I could simply look up the answers after calculating them once.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a bound on how long the input string may be?  Is there a run-time limit, or a presumption that only a solution that scales optimally is acceptable?

Comment: Optimally scaling is preferred - but not a huge requirements. In general the input string will be fairly small (anywhere from 3-20 in length).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give start help, with the approach for such a solution.

- formal problem statement;
- data model;
- algorithm;
- heuristics, cleverness.

For N digits there are some 3^N possibilities.
The solution must model the running data as:

- the `digits`, as `int[]`
- the `sum`
- `index` from which to advance, prior digits were done.
- number `part`already tried, plus `sign`. Sign must come separate (as -1, +1) as the coming digit may be 0;

(What I leave out is the collecting of the entire result.)

The brute force solution then could be:

```
boolean solve(int[] digits, int sum) {
    return solve(digits, sum, 1, 0, 0);
}

boolean solve(int[] digits, int sum, int signum, int part, int index) {
    if (index >= digits.length) {
        return signum * part == sum;
    }
    // Before the digit at index do either nothing, +, or -
    return solve(digits, sum, signum, part * 10 + digits[index], index + 1)
            || solve(digits, sum - signum * part, 1, 0, index + 1)
            || solve(digits, sum - signum * part, -1, 0, index + 1);
}
```

Mind you could also split the digits in half and try to insert (nothing, +, -) there.

There are pruning opportunities, to diminish the number of tries. First the above can be done in a loop, the alternatives need not all to be tried. The order of evaluation might favor more likely candidates:

- if digit 0 ...
- if part > sum first - then +
- ...

Unfortunately +/- make a number theoretical approach AFAIK for me illusory.

> @dasblinkenlight mentions even better data models, allowing to not
>   repeat evaluation in the alternatives. That would be even more
>   interesting. But might fail miserably due to time constraints. And I
>   wanted to come with something concrete. Without providing an entirely
>   ready made solution.

Comment: Thank you for this approach - I am currently working through the problem and making progress thanks to this post.

Answer (score 5):

> I could possibly create a recursive loop function to create every possible combination of the string and see if each result matches but this seems like it will be terribly slow.

Doing an exhaustive search is your only option here. Fortunately, the timing isn't going to be too bad even for moderately long strings of up to 7..10 characters, because you do not need to "redo" additions and subtractions of a prior string when you process the "tail".

An outline of a possible implementation could be as follows:

1. Put all desired results from your array of integers in a hash set
2. Make a recursive method that takes the result so far, the string, and the position of the next "cut"
3. When the next "cut" is at the end of the string, check the result so far against the hash set from step 1
4. Otherwise, try these three possibilities in a loop on `k`

   - Use a `k`-digit number from the "cut" as a positive number, and make a recursive invocation with the "cut" moved by `k` digits. This is equivalent to inserting a `+` at the cut
   - Use a `k`-digit number from the "cut" as a negative number, and make a recursive invocation with the "cut" moved by `k` digits. This is equivalent to inserting a `-` at the cut

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to take a brute force approach if you can rely on the input string not to be too long.  If it contains `n` digits then you can construct 3<sup>n-1</sup> formulae from it (between each pair of digits you can insert '+', '-', or nothing, for `n-1` internal positions).  For a 12-digit input string that's roughly 270000 formulae, which should be computable quite quickly.  Of course, you would build and compute each one once, and compare the result to all the alternatives.  Don't redo the computation for each array element.

It may be that there's a dynamic programming approach to this, but I'm not immediately seeing it, at least not one that would be substantially better than brute force.